# Where can I find historic version info after a GKE Cluster upgrade?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Where can I find historic version info after a GKE Cluster upgrade?

We recently had an automatic update, and I'm wondering what version we had before this current version. Is it found in GCP somwhere? Or can I use `kubectl`?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check your `Audit Logs` and run the following query:

```
resource.type="gke_cluster" AND
log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity")
protoPayload.methodName="google.container.internal.ClusterManagerInternal.UpdateClusterInternal"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I believe that only gives us the general update history? I'm looking for information about versions as well. From what and to what version.